# ( AttributeError: 'Clientes' object has no attribute '_session')

Tags: python, base-de-datos, kivy, sqlalchemy

### Mi problema se da en la clase clientes cuando presiono el boton de guardar no se si falta algun atributo o metodo se los agradaceria

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
```

---

Este esta es tabla pedidos de mi modelo de la clase Clientes

```
class Pedido(Base):
__tablename__ = 'pedidos'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
nombre = Column(String)
apellido = Column(String)
email = Column(String)
producto = Column(String)
```

---

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle ,Line
from kivy.graphics.instructions import *
#import mComercio as mCom
```

---

Aca empieza mi programa que tiene de nombre PantallaCatalogos

```
class PantallaPrincipal(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, app):
       super(PantallaPrincipal, self).__init__()
       self.app = app
       self.crearWidgets(self)

    def crearWidgets(self, desde = None):
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.orientation = 'horizontal'
       boton = Button()
       boton.text='Catalogo de Productos'
       boton.font_size = 60
       boton.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
       boton.on_press= self.mostrarPantallaCatalogo
       self.add_widget(boton)

    def mostrarPantallaCatalogo(self,desde = None):
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.add_widget(PantallaCatalogo(self))
```

---

Para acceder a la otra Pantalla presionar el boton Vinos

```
class PantallaCatalogo(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, PantallaPrincipal):
       super(PantallaCatalogo, self).__init__()
       self.pantallaPrincipal = PantallaPrincipal
       self.cols = 7
       self.orientation = 'vertical'
       self.add_widget(Button(text= 'Vinos', background_normal
       =('imagenes/H600_8583-b.png'), on_press = self.mostrarPantallaVinos))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='Carnes', background_normal  =('imagenes/Distintos-tipos-carnes_1235286477_343312_660x372.jpg')))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='Lacteos', background_normal =('imagenes/los-lacteos-en-reposteria.jpg')))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='Electrodomesticos', background_normal =('imagenes/electrodomesticos-cocina.jpg')))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='Frutas y Verduras', background_normal =('imagenes/verduras y frutas.jpg')))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='volver', background_color = (0,0,1,1),on_press = PantallaPrincipal.crearWidgets))

    def mostrarPantallaVinos(self,desde = None):
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.add_widget(PantallaVinos(self))
```

---

aca para acceder a la otra pantalla desde el boton Marcas

```
class PantallaVinos(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, PantallaPrincipal):
       super(PantallaVinos, self).__init__()
       self.orientation= 'vertical'
       self.add_widget(Button(text='Marcas', background_normal =('imagenes/H600_8583-b.png'), on_press = self.mostrarProducto))
       self.add_widget(Button(text='1'))

    def mostrarProducto(self,desde = None):
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.add_widget(mostrarProducto(self))
```

---

ahora para acceder a la otra pantalla desde el boton ingresar hasta llegar a la Clase Clientes

```
class mostrarProducto(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, PantallaPrincipal):
       super(mostrarProducto, self).__init__()
       self.orientation= "vertical"
       barra = GridLayout()
       barra.orientation= "horizontal"
       barra.cols = 7
       barra.size_hint= (1, 0.8)
       barra.add_widget(Image(source='imagenes/verduras y frutas.jpg'))
       barra.add_widget(Image(source='imagenes/Distintos-tipos-carnes_1235286477_343312_660x372.jpg'))
       barra.add_widget(Image(source='imagenes/electrodomesticos-cocina.jpg'))
       barra.add_widget(Image(source='imagenes/H600_8583-b.png'))
       barra.add_widget(Image(source='imagenes/los-lacteos-en-reposteria.jpg'))
       self.add_widget(barra)
       barra_abajo = BoxLayout()
       barra_abajo.orientation = "vertical"
       barra_abajo.size_hint= (1, 0.2)
       barra_abajo.add_widget(Label(text="¿No encuentra lo que busca?"))
       barra_abajo.add_widget(Label(text="Haga su pedido"))
       barra_abajo.add_widget(Button(text="Ingresar",background_color = (1,1,0,1), on_press = self.Clientes))
       self.add_widget(barra_abajo)

    def Clientes(self,desde = None):
       self.clear_widgets()
       self.add_widget(Clientes(self))
```

*Mi problema se da en la clase clientes cuando presiono el boton guardar  *

```
class Clientes(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, PantallaPrincipal):
       super(Clientes, self).__init__()
       self.orientation = 'vertical'
       #rect = Rectangle(source=('imagenes/fondo.jpg'), size= (2000,1800))
       #self.canvas.add(rect)
       self.add_widget(Label(text='Nombre',font_size = 30,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.8},size_hint= (None, None),size=(150, 100)))
       self.inp_nombre = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.8},size_hint= (None, None),size=(500, 100))
       self.add_widget(self.inp_nombre)
       self.add_widget(Label(text='Apellido',font_size = 30,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.6},size_hint= (None, None),size=(150, 100)))
       self.inp_apellido = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.6},size_hint=(None, None),size=(500, 100))
       self.add_widget(self.inp_apellido)
       self.add_widget(Label(text='Correo Electronico',font_size = 30,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.4},size_hint=(None, None),size=(150, 100)))
       self.inp_correo = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.4},size_hint= (None, None),size=(500, 100))
       self.add_widget(self.inp_correo)
       self.add_widget(Label(text='Producto que necesita',font_size = 29,pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.2},size_hint= (None, None),size=(150, 100)))
       self.inp_producto = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.2},size_hint=(None, None),size=(500, 100))
       self.add_widget(self.inp_producto)
       self.btn_enviar = Button(text='Enviar',pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.05},size_hint= (None, None), size=(100, 30))
       self.btn_enviar.bind(on_press=self.hacer_pedido)
       self.add_widget(self.btn_enviar)

    def hacer_pedido(self, instance):
       nombre = self.inp_nombre.text
       apellido = self.inp_apellido.text
       correo = self.inp_correo.text
       producto = self.inp_producto.text
       pedido = Pedido(nombre=nombre, apellido=apellido, email=correo, producto=producto)
       s = self._session()
       s.add(pedido)
       s.commit()
       s.close()

class ComercioApp(App):
    def build(self):
       self._engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tienda.sqlite')
       self._session = sessionmaker()
       self._session.configure(bind=self._engine)
       Base.metadata.create_all(self._engine)
       return PantallaPrincipal(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ComercioApp().run()
```

Comment: Desconozco qué framework estás utilizando, pero leyendo tu código veo que la clase `Clientes` contiene el método `hacer_pedido` y en él haces `s = self._session()`, pero me da la impresión de que antes tienes que inicializar `self._session()`.

Comment: me podrias ayudar a corregirlo

Comment: En `ComercioApp` defines `self._session` y veo que pasas `self` contínuamente de un lado a otro. Revisa que al pasar `self` a `Clientes` realmente le estás pasando `self._session`. Ten además cuidado con usar guión bajo antes del nombre de un atributo (`_session`), en python esto se considera atributo privado.

Comment: gracias tenias razon ya lo solucione muchas gracias